# How can I input strings into java?

Tags: java, string, netbeans

I know I have to use the Scanner class to first create the scanner object to receive user input in java, although I don't know how to input multiple words into one string variable. For example, I have this code here:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the following information");

System.out.print("Author:");
author = input.nextLine();

System.out.print("Title:");
title = input.nextLine();

System.out.print("Grade Level:");
gradeLevel = input.nextDouble();


System.out.print("Pages:");
pages = input.nextDouble();
```

Which according to many forums, should allow the user to input the entire line into the String variable, but instead, it skips the Author prompt entirely. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I have added the full loop below:

```
do {

    System.out.printf("What kind of book is this?\n"
            + "(0 = Textbook, 1 = Novel, 2 = Biography, 3 = Author Information, 4 = Other)");

    switch(input.nextInt()) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Please enter the following information.");

            System.out.print("Author:");
            author = input.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Title:");
            title = input.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Grade Level:");
            gradeLevel = input.nextDouble();
            input.readLine();

            System.out.print("Pages:");
            pages = input.nextDouble();

            //Creation of textBooks
            texts[i] = new Textbook(gradeLevel, author, pages, title);

            boolText = true;
            break;
        case 1:
            System.out.print("Please enter the following information.\n");

            System.out.print("Author:");
            author = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Genre:");
            genre = input.next();
            System.out.print("Title:");
            title = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Pages:");
            pages = input.nextDouble();

            //Creation of Novels
            novels[i] = new Novel(genre, title, author, pages);

            boolNovel = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.print("Please enter the following information.\n");

            System.out.print("Author:");
            author = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Title:");
            title = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Subject:");
            subject = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Pages:");
            pages = input.nextDouble();

            //Creation of Biographies
            bio[i] = new Biography(subject, title, author, pages);

            boolBiography = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.print("Please enter the following information.\n");

            System.out.print("Author:");
            author = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Email:");
            email = input.next();
            System.out.print("Address:");
            address = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Number of Titles:");
            numOfTitles = input.nextDouble();

            //Creation of Author Infortmation
            authors[i] = new Author(author, address, email, numOfTitles);

            boolAuthor = true;
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Please enter the following information.");

            System.out.print("Title:");
            title = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Author:");
            author = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Pages:");
            pages = input.nextDouble();

            //Creation of Author Infortmation
            other[i] = new Books(title, author, pages);

            boolOther = true;
        default:
            System.out.println("Program will now terminate.");
            System.exit(1);
    }

    i++;
    }
    while (i < t);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have this in a loop? There's probably a /n character still in the buffer. At the top, add: `input.nextLine();`

Comment: Yes, sorry this is in a switch statement that's within a do-while loop.

Answer (score 4):

Ordinarily this does work but more than likely you are using this code in a loop. Since `nextDouble` does not consume newline characters you will need to consume this character explicitly

```
pages = input.nextDouble();
input.readLine() // added - consumes newline
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are running it inside a loop

```
pages = input.nextDouble();
input.readLine()
```

This will solve it. That's why `Author` prompt just skips to next since it has got the input. i.e `\n` (new line character from previous double input value)

Comment: Am I missing something, where has he said this is in a loop?

Comment: Generally, skipping problem happens in loop because of unconsumed characters

Comment: I tried adding input.readLine() but netbeans gave me errors. From what I understand, netbeans is taken each word for the author name as separate variables.